# could not find space (100 bytes) for variable in "C"

Tags: c, arrays, memory, embedded, pic

I want to display serial data from uart. To validate the data I used some variables and arrays. For array declaration I've declared

```
unsigned char  stringRead[MAXSIZE];
unsigned char  tempString[MAXSIZE];
```

After compiling the code im getting below errors

```
could not find space (100 bytes) for variable _stringRead
could not find space (100 bytes) for variable _tempString
```

I changed size to 100 bytes `stringRead[100]` and `tempString[100]"` and compiled. Still the problem remains. Some suggested that use `const unsigned char`, it also didn't work for me. Below is the complete code.

```
#include "Includes.h"
#define CR         0x0d
#define LF         0x0a
#define ESC        0x1b
#define BEEP       0x07
#define SPACE     0x20
#define COMMA     0x2C
#define MAXSIZE    100
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>        /* required for the isalnum function */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
unsigned char  charRead;        /* char read from COM port */
unsigned char  stringRead[100]; /* Buffer collects chars read from GPS */
unsigned char  tempString[100];
unsigned char  timeString[12];
unsigned char  latitudeString[11];
unsigned char  latitudeCardinalString[3];
unsigned char  longitudeString[12];
unsigned char  longitudeCardinalString[3];
unsigned char  *pChar;
unsigned char  dummyChar;
unsigned  long utcTime, estTime;      /* Coordinated Universal Time and Eastern Standard Time */
unsigned  long utcHour, estHour;
unsigned  long utcMinutes, estMinutes;
unsigned  long utcSeconds, estSeconds;
unsigned  char lastCommaPosition;
float    latitude;
int      latDegrees;
float    latMinutes;
float    longitude;
int      longDegrees;
float    longMinutes;
// FILE *gpsFile;        /* Text file of GPS strings read */
unsigned int   j, k;   /* dummy variable */
unsigned int   i;    /* Number of chars read per GPS message string */
unsigned int   numLinesRead;    /* Number of GPS strings read */

//dummyChar = 'A'; pChar = &dummyChar;

//#include "dos.h"
// Configuration word for PIC16F877A
__CONFIG(0x3f72);

// Main Function
char mah;
void main(void)
{
InitUART();                         // Intialize UART
while(1)
{
mah=ReceiveByteSerially();
SendByteSerially(mah);

do {
      charRead = mah;      /* read char from serial port */
      if(charRead == '$') {     /* GPS messages start with $ char */
      i = 0;
      numLinesRead++;
      stringRead[i] = charRead;
      do {
         charRead = mah;
         if( (charRead != '\0') && (isalnum(charRead) ||     isspace(charRead) || ispunct(charRead)) ) {
        i++;
        stringRead[i] = charRead;
         }
      } while(charRead != CR);

      /* By this point, a complete GPS string has been read so save it to file */
      /* Append the null terminator to the string read */
      stringRead[i+1] = '\0';

      /* Analyze string that we collected */
      j = 0;
      pChar = stringRead;
      while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
           tempString[j] = *(pChar+j);
           j++;
      }
      tempString[j] = '\0';

      /* Check if string we collected is the $GPGGA message */
      if(tempString[3] == 'G' && tempString[4] == 'G' && tempString[5] == 'A') {
          pChar = stringRead;

          /* Get UTC time */
          j = 7;  /* start of time field */
          k = 0;
          while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
           timeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
           j++;
           k++;
          }
          lastCommaPosition = j;
          timeString[k] = '\0';
          sscanf(timeString, "%ld", &utcTime);
          utcHour = (utcTime/10000);   /* extract Hours from long */
          utcMinutes = (utcTime - (utcHour*10000))/100;
          utcSeconds = utcTime - (utcHour*10000) - (utcMinutes*100); 

          if(utcHour >= 4 && utcHour <= 23) estHour = utcHour - 4;
        else estHour = utcHour + 20;
          estMinutes = utcMinutes;
          estSeconds = utcSeconds;
printf("%02ld:%02ld:%02ld UTC = %02ld:%02ld:%02ld EST",  utcHour, utcMinutes, utcSeconds, estHour, estMinutes, estSeconds);

          /* Get lattitude: ddmm.mmmm */
          pChar = stringRead;
          j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
          k = 0;
          while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
           latitudeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
           j++;
           k++;
          }
          lastCommaPosition = j;
          latitudeString[k] = '\0';

          sscanf(latitudeString, "%f", &latitude);
          latDegrees = (int)(latitude/100);
          latMinutes = (float)(latitude - latDegrees*100);
          printf("/t%02d DEG/t%2.4f MIN", latDegrees, latMinutes);

          /* Get lattitude Cardinal direction */
          pChar = stringRead;
          j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
          k = 0;
          while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
           latitudeCardinalString[k] = *(pChar+j);
           j++;
           k++;
          }
          lastCommaPosition = j;
          latitudeCardinalString[k] = '\0';
          printf(" %s", latitudeCardinalString);

          /* Get longitude: dddmm.mmmm */
          pChar = stringRead;
          j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
          k = 0;
          while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
           longitudeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
           j++;
           k++;
          }
          lastCommaPosition = j;
          longitudeString[k] = '\0';

          sscanf(longitudeString, "%f", &longitude);
          longDegrees = (int)(longitude/100);
          longMinutes = (float)(longitude - longDegrees*100);
          printf("/t%03d DEG/t%2.4f MIN", longDegrees, longMinutes);

          printf("/n");
      } /* else not a GPGGA sentence */

      //fprintf(gpsFile, "%d: (%d) %s/n", numLinesRead, i, stringRead);

      } /* otherwise not a $ character... so loop back until one arrives */
  } while(!kbhit());

  printf("Exiting...");
//      close_com();   /* Finished with serial port so close it */
//    fclose(gpsFile);
//  printf("done/n");
//  return (0);

 }
 //SendByteSerially(RCREG);

 }
```

Comment: C or C#?!? Are those non-static, local variables?

Comment: @KerrekSB It is "C". They are not local variables.

Comment: You may not have set up your stack(s) correctly. How to do this will depend on whatever processor you are working with as well as your toolchain.

Comment: Need to see the full source and makefile.  You might be putting those arrays in some section that you didn't mean to.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C# and C?

Comment: @JS1 [link]http://www.4shared.com/office/jCyzVrDkba/code.html

Comment: Please edit your post and put the code there instead of linking.

Comment: What's your build target?  Is it an embedded device?  Is your program exceeding them memory size of your target?

Comment: It is entirely possible that one of your include files also defines MAXSIZE...

Comment: @JS1 Yes. Its an PIC microcontroller.

Comment: @technosaurus i just defines the MAXSIZE in "include.h" file. Still its shows the same error.

Comment: "PIC microcontroller" covers a vast number of parts with widely differing resources; be specific.

Comment: My point is that you should include your system libraries first.  It is not uncommon for a header to have something like `#undef MAXSIZE` ... `#define MAXSIZE 65535` or whatever ... best practice is to do system includes, then project includes and _then_ define local constants.   It likely has nothing to do with it at all (yet) ... you may just be out of stack space which is remedied by using malloc to put them on the heap instead.

Comment: @user25770 From the wikipedia article I just read about the PIC microcontroller, it appears you have 256 bytes or less of addressible data space.  So apparently you just don't have room for static 100 byte arrays.  You will probably need to use some kind of banking mechanism.  By the way, I count at least 100 bytes being used by all your other global variables.  That along with globals used by your libraries is probably occupying enough data space to leave you with less than 100 bytes left out of 256.

Comment: What is the exit for?  Where will it exit to?  What will it do when it gets there? Generally the loop would be indefinite and stopping is a case of switching off the power.

Answer (score 4):

Comments in the code suggest that you are targeting a PIC16F877; that part has only 368 bytes of RAM, so your use of statically allocated global data is somewhat profligate.  That applies to not just these arrays.

Better modularisation (not all code in `main()`)  and use of local temporary storage will lead to more efficient memory use.  Or perhaps you should select a part more suited to your application - though don't let that stop you from fixing the inefficient design.

Note also that an NMEA0183/IEC61662-1 format message as output by most GNSS modules has a maximum length of 80 characters including CR+LF terminator, so you could reduce stringRead to 81, and tempString probably need be that long.  However, in fact there is no need to buffer the entire message in any case.

The implementation below uses no buffering whatsoever and far fewer variables, constants or headers (most of your includes were redundant), and [no globals](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals), so overall will have a much smaller RAM footprint than yours and is therefore more suited to your platform.  I have avoided `sprintf` because it is likely somewhat memory hungry too, it would be good also to avoid `printf`, but doing so is less straightforward so I've left it as an exercise ;-). It compiles as C99 code, though obviously I have not tested it in execution - in may have flaws, but you can see the idea.

```
#include "Includes.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// Helper functions
void waitRxChar( char ch ) ;
static float minutesFieldRx() ;
static int twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;
static int threeDigitIntFieldRx() ;

void main( void )
{
    InitUART() ;

    // Process GGA incomming sentences
    // $--GGA,hhmmss.ss,ddmm.mmmm,N|S,dddmm.mmmm,E|W,q,s,hdop,alt,altM,G,GM,age,diffid*hh<CR><LF>
    static const char* GGA_FORMAT = "GGA" ;
    for(;;)
    {
        // Wait for $--GGA,
        int i = 0 ;
        while( GGA_FORMAT[i] != 0 )
        {
            waitRxChar( '$' ) ;

            // Skip talker ID, could be GP, GL, GN, GA or other GNSS ID
            ReceiveByteSerially() ;
            ReceiveByteSerially() ;

            // Match GGA, restart from $ on mismatch
            do 
            {
                char rxch = ReceiveByteSerially() ;
                if( rxch == GGA_FORMAT[i] )
                {
                   i++ ;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 0 ; // Not GGA, restart search from $
                }
            } while( i != 0 && GGA_FORMAT[i] != 0 ) ;
        } 

        // Skip comma field separator
        ReceiveByteSerially() ;

        // Get UTC time
        int hh = twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;
        int mm = twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;
        int ss = twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;

        // Output UTC + EST
        printf( "%02ld:%02ld:%02ld UTC = %02ld:%02ld:%02ld EST", hh, mm, ss, (hh + 20) % 24, mm, ss );

        // May have fractions of a second, so discard all until field delimiter
        waitRxChar( ',' ) ;

        // Get lattitude ddmm.mmmm,N|S
        int deg = twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;
        float min = minutesFieldRx() ;
        char hemisphere = ReceiveByteSerially() ; 

        // Output lattitude
        printf( "/t%02d DEG/t%2.4f MIN %c", deg, min, hemisphere );

        // Get longitude dddmm.mmmm,E|W
        deg = threeDigitIntFieldRx() ;
        min = minutesFieldRx() ;
        hemisphere = ReceiveByteSerially() ; 

        // Output longitude
        printf( "/t%03d DEG/t%2.4f MIN %c", deg, min, hemisphere );

        // Newline
        putchar( '\n' ) ;
    }
}

void waitRxChar( char ch )
{
    // wait for start character
    while( ReceiveByteSerially() != ch )
    {
        // spin
    }
}

float minutesFieldRx()
{
    float float_field = 0.0f ;
    float pv = 10 ;
    char rxch = 0 ;
    do
    {
        rxch = ReceiveByteSerially() ;
        if( rxch != ',' )
        {
            float_field += (rxch - '0') * pv ;
            pv /= 10 ;
        }
    } while ( rxch != ',' ) ;

    return float_field ;
}

int twoDigitIntFieldRx()
{
    return (ReceiveByteSerially() - '0') * 10 + 
           (ReceiveByteSerially() - '0') ;
}

int threeDigitIntFieldRx()
{
    return (ReceiveByteSerially() - '0') * 100 + 
           twoDigitIntFieldRx() ;
}
```

It is possible to reduce the stack memory footprint further at the expense of readability and ease of debugging by omitting temporary variables altogether. For example:

```
    // Output lattitude
    printf( "/t%02d DEG/t%2.4f MIN %c", twoDigitIntFieldRx(), 
                                        minutesFieldRx(),                        
                                        ReceiveByteSerially());
```